# What it the best file server with Ubuntu Server and Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, file-server

I'm developing file server client (Windows 10 Environment) with Electron.

But, First I have to decide what file server that I use. So I search it from Google, but it's really hard to find what I want.

But I have to follow these instructions.

Can access from external Internet Speed is important (We use 2Gbps internet connection now.) Can Create, Read, Modify, Delete in Network drive folder (or mount as Local drive) Do not use 3rd party program like, Netdrive or Raidrive. (Can connect with Windows 10 default network drive connection function) Can give permission so that classify folder (ex) employee folder & CEO folder This is the list that I found.

(X) - FTP -> Cannot mapping with network drive. Only can connect with 'network location'
(X) - SFTP -> Same reason with FTP
(▲) - SSHFS (SSH) -> It works well but, need to install WinFSP & SSHFS-Win. And It has some Encoding problem from file name. (It seems that theses library did not use UTF-8 Encoding. Some Charsets are broken)
(▲) - WebDav -> It works well but, it can only upload 4gb(But in Ubuntu with Apache2 it can only upload 2gb) below and it has some permission problems.
(X) - DFS -> It can only open with Windows Operating system
(X) - SAMBA -> Cannot Access from External Network

So I think I have two options to choose. SSHFS or WebDAV.

I think simple way is WebDAV but, I have to consider upload limit (But I think there are not many times to upload over 4GB files. Second, SSHFS is works really fine, and When I use SSHFS-WIN-Manager with WinFsp, SSHFS-Win it really, works fine to me. But it has file name encoding problem. (But I have to try fix the code to fix it, because I have to develop new Client program)

What is the best option? or is there any other way to solve this problem (ex: another file server system...)

It seems that mapping with network drive or local drive, it needs dokan library. If there is no options in above, I have to practice to control dokan libary.

Any advise or answer can helps me a lot.